# Reduction of $f$-solubility to $1$-factor

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

This has been put in math.SE for a while without any responses.

> Given $G$ and an $f:V(G)\to{\Bbb N}$, there exists a graph $G_f$ such that $G$ is $f$-soluble if and only if $G_f$ has a $1$-factor.

"G is $f$-soluble" is defined as a graph such that there exists $w:E(G)\to{\Bbb N}$ such that
$$
\sum_{uv\in E(G)}w(uv)=f(v)
$$
for every $v\in V(G)$.

I believe this is a result from Tutte and it might be related to the $f$-factor theorem. But I don't remember the whole proof. One key step I remember is defining
$$
V(G_f):=\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_{f(v)}|v\in V(G)\}.
$$
Could anyone come up with a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a theorem that Tutte used to derive the f-factor theorem from the 1-factor theorem. He had already proved the f-factor theorem directly in 1952, in "The factors of graphs", [MR0048775](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=48775). The result you quote is from his paper from two years later, "A short proof of the factor theorem for finite graphs", [MR0063008](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=63008).

If you have trouble locating the reference, I can update this answer to give the actual argument, and construction of what you call $G_f$.